# Keyboard Shortcut for Mirroring Display on Mac OS X

Tags: macos, mac, multiple-monitors, mirroring

I have a MacBook with a broken display. I would like to use a new monitor but I can not see to enable the mirroring option. Is there any key command to enable mirroring?

Comment: If you plug in a keyboard and mouse, you could leave the lid closed and use your computer in Clamshell Mode.  http://support.apple.com/kb/ht3131

Answer (score 14):

From [the Apple site](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht5019):

<kbd>⌘ Command</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd>

or

<kbd>F7</kbd>

Comment: Good info, but answer could be a little nicer. I just tried to find this info with Google but it was pretty tricky. Lots of false positives.

Comment: To be fair, it's hard to google stuff with a broken display...

Comment: Yea, and more importantly, how do I disable this command?

Comment: This doesn't seem to work when using a PC keyboard with my mac mini. Any ideas?

Comment: Worst. Hotkey. Ever. Never needed it, only every pressed it accidentally, and didn’t know how to switch back (without going into display settings). Meanwhile, the mirroring breaks my window layout.

Comment: Best. Hotkey. Ever. Always use it, especially when giving presos. Just toggles back and forth between multiple-display and mirror.

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>command</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd>

Comment: Correct for recent Macs. Older ones use F7, as in Brad's answer.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work when using a PC keyboard with my mac mini. Any ideas?

Comment: Worst. Hotkey. Ever. Never needed it, only every pressed it accidentally, and didn’t know how to switch back (without going into display settings). Meanwhile, the mirroring breaks my window layout.

Answer (score 0):

These answers didn't work for me... using iMac in the Disk Utility on the Leopard install disc.

I did happen to hit <kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> and turn on VoiceOver, which got me through the dark.